# LVM recovery after loss of system drive

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, lvm, data-recovery

I have made a LVM using multiple HDDs. The OS was installed on a different SSD. I lost that SSD. How can I recover the LVM from those HDDs?

Comment: With a separate or spare bootable disk (a new SSD, HDD, 
or even a USB stick), install the
OS and LVM tools to the spare disk, boot from that disk,
and use the LVM tools to recover the LVM. 
In future, consider keeping a spare bootable drive available.

Comment: Specifically, I would start with [pvscan](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pvscan.8.html).

Answer (score 2):

If the failed SSD was not part of the volume group, then the group is still whole: any modern Linux equipped with LVM tools should normally auto-activate the volume group as the disks are detected at boot time. If you run `sudo vgscan`, it will tell you about any volume groups on any disks it can see. If a volume group is missing one (or more) of its components, it will tell you the LVM UUID of the missing volume.

If `sudo vgscan` displays no errors, then it will be just a matter of mounting the logical volumes, and if you want the mounts to be persistent, writing new `/etc/fstab` entries for them as appropriate.

---

If the failed SSD was also included in the same volume group, then the VG will now be incomplete and will not activate automatically, and `sudo vgscan` will report a missing physical volume.

To activate such a partial volume group, you can use `sudo vgchange -ay --activationmode partial`: all logical volumes that are at least partially on the remaining disks will be activated, but if a logical volume was partially located on a disk that is now lost, trying to read that part of the logical volume will result in an error. Trying to mount a LV that has parts missing is likely to fail.

You could run e.g. `sudo lvs -o lv_full_name,lv_health_status` to see the names and health statuses of each of your LVs. If a LV's entry in the "Health" column is blank, it will be OK; if it says "partial", some part of the LV is missing. To find out which part is missing, you can use `sudo lvdisplay -m <VG name>/<LV name>`.

Any logical volumes that had all their parts on the HDDs can now be mounted as usual. If you have a logical volume that was only partially on the lost disk, you can use recovery tools like `photorec` or `ddrescue` to try and recover data from the remaining parts of those logical volumes.

If you have such a partial logical volume and decide that its remaining contents are not worth recovering, or are satisfied that you've recovered everything you can, then you can use `lvremove` to delete the partial logical volume(s), then `vgreduce --removemissing <VG name>` to tell LVM to stop remembering the missing physical volume. After that, the volume group with the remaining volumes will behave again as if the failed PV was never there: it will auto-activate when the complete set of PVs are detected (i.e. at boot or on hot-plug), and any remaining logical volumes can be mounted normally.